# CheckIndex -fix argument not working from command line

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to recover a failed ES shard and I've been seen a few tutorials which cite the docs below:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/CheckIndex.html

But I'm not able to run the following command because the -fix flag doesn't work.

`/usr/share/elasticsearch/lib$ java -cp lucene-core*.jar -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex "/var/lib/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/l1VcSQySRmuyFGTBBPjX9g/0/index/" -fix`

`ERROR: unexpected extra argument '-fix'`

Answer (score 3):

That argument has been changed to `-exorcise`, presumably to emphasize that if it finds problematic segments, it just removes them altogether, rather than attempting to fix or reconstruct them, in order to get the index into a readable state.